# Оправка строки на сервер с формы HTML

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, jstl

Есть строки, которые выводятся циклом на страницу. Мне необходимо при нажатии на кнопку отправить данные товара на сервер, который занесет этот заказ в таблицу.

Кнопку при помощи `form` сделал, `id` пользователя определяется по сессии.

Но `id` товара, цена не передается.
Чем заменить `input`?

Надо убрать этот ввод.

```jsp
<c:forEach var="parts" items="${parts}" varStatus="status">
    <li class="product-wrapper">

        <div class="product-item">

            <img src="${parts.img}"/>
            <div class="product-list">
                <h3>${parts.name}</h3>
                <form action="frontController?command=createord" method="post">
                    <input class="id" name="${parts.id}">
                    <input class="price" name="${parts.price}" value="${parts.price}">
                    <input type="number"
                           min="0"
                           max="10"
                           step="1"
                           value="1" name="quantity" id="quantity">
                    <input type="submit" values="
    <p><ftm:message bundle="${i18n}" key="ord.create"/>"></p>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

**Код контроллера:**

```
public class CreateOrdConroller implements Controller {
private OrdService ordService = OrdServiceIpl.getInstance();
@Override
public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
    User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    long userId = user.getId();
    String id = req.getParameter("id");
    Long parts_id = Long.parseLong(id);
    String parts_price = req.getParameter("price");
    Double price = Double.parseDouble(parts_price);
    String quantity_parts = req.getParameter("quantity");
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity_parts);
    ordService.createOrder(userId,parts_id,quantity);

}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы убрать ввод, надо заменить `input` элементы на другие, которые не видны для пользователя.

```
<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="${parts.id}">
<input type="hidden" class="price" name="price" value="${parts.price}">
```

Невидимые поля будут передаваться в контроллер, и могут быть получены как параметры запроса.

Answer (score -1):

Контролируйте цену на сервере, создайте таблицу с ценами к товарам и передавайте в реквесте только количество

Comment: Не является ответом, на вопрос. Это может быть комментарием, или может быть удалено, так как не имеет отношения к проблеме ОП.